# web form to generate ad-hoc sql statements

Tags: c#, adhoc, adhoc-queries

I have a task to build asp.net C# web form to allow end user to generate sql queries.

Very similar to this one:  [EasyQuery.NET WebForms](http://ajax.easyquerydemo.com/Default.aspx)

However I'm not allowed to use any 3rd party DLL's or spend big $ on full source versions.
*My boss would rather force me to work overtime and re-invent the wheel.*

Any tips on this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free web based query builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069543/free-web-based-query-builder)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against this - you open yourself up to a whole host of  [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection)  attacks. You might be able to consider using OData and then expose a query engine like they used for the [StackExchange OData Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Right, but depends on how it's used. If it's in an admin panel where only the site owner has access I doubt he'll purposely truncate is own tables.